# How to merge completely different dataframe UP-SIDE in Python

Tags: python, pandas

these are my Dataframes,

these are  diff CSV files and I want to merge it into a single CSV.

Is it possible?

```
df1

a b b1 c d
1 1  2 3 3
1 2  1 3 4
5 5  5 6 4

df2

r t y 
3 5 6 
6 2 1


i want to merge this horizontally

expected output-:

a b b1 c d
1 1  2 3 3
1 2  1 3 4
5 5  5 6 4

r t y 
3 5 6 
6 2 1
```

I used `pd.merge` and `pd.join` but i was not able to do that
Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output again?

Comment: What is the expected output? please post an output you want?

Comment: Could you please provide the code you have tried and the output so that other users  can replicate your problem?

Comment: @HenryYik added

Comment: @DejeneT. added

Comment: Do you mean `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)`?

Comment: @HenryYik it doesn't work actually, assume there are two diff tables in CSV, and i want to  merge it into single one(i mean (UP-DOWN)), this will  merge "side by side"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
df1 = df1.T.reset_index().T
df2 = df2.T.reset_index().T

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0).fillna("").reset_index(drop=True)

df.columns = df.loc[0,:]
df.drop(labels=0, inplace=True)
```

output,

```
0  a  b b1  c  d
1  1  1  2  3  3
2  1  2  1  3  4
3  5  5  5  6  4
4  r  t  y      
5  3  5  6      
6  6  2  1
```

Comment: woah!! can you tell me how to remove, first column(0,1,2,3,4) ?

Comment: what will be the column label's ?

Comment: those letters , I don't want "0,1,2,3,4" bottom side is done as per this code, and it is also fine if there is no column name in CSV!